# WiX Changing UI behavior based on registry value

Tags: wix, registry, wix3.5

The short version is that I am building an installer package, and I want the “Next” button of my welcome screen to change its behavior based on whether or not a specific registry key exists.  It seems like I should be able to modify the conditions of the next button’s actions to get this behavior, but so far no luck.  I always either get behavior A or behavior B, I have not gotten behavior that is sensitive to the registry value.

I should note that I can remove the UI completely and run the package via command line to get the desired results, but I am trying to be a little more user friendly by adding the install path dialog when appropriate.

In a bit more detail…

I am working on installers for a series of independent, but related, class libraries.  If we install a library on a clean box I want the installer to prompt the user for an install path, and then write this path off to the registry during the install process.  However if we install a library on a box which already has one of the other libraries present, I want the installer to read the registry and use the same path as the previous install.

My thought process was to modify the standard WixUI_InstallDir interface to check for the registry search result and skip the InstallDirDlg if it is set.  However this does not appear to be working.  Here are some snips from the XML:

```
<Property Id="FOOPATH">
  <RegistrySearch Id="PathSet" Type="directory" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Foo" Name="InstallPath"></RegistrySearch>
</Property>
<Property Id="PATHSET">
  <RegistrySearch Id="PathSet" Type="directory" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Foo" Name="InstallPath"></RegistrySearch>
</Property>

<Directory Id="FOOPATH" Name="Foo">
  <Component Id="FooPathReg" Guid="Some Guid">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Foo" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
      <RegistryValue Name="InstallPath" Type="string" Value="[FOOPATH]" KeyPath="yes"></RegistryValue>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
</Directory>

<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">NOT Installed AND NOT PATHSET</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">NOT Installed AND PATHSET</Publish>
```

If my publish conditions are using the PATHSET property (as shown) then I always get the install directory dialog, if I switch them to use the FOOPATH property then I never get the dialog.  I have also tried playing with the InstallUISequence and it does not seem to matter how early I schedule the AppSearch action, I still get the same result.

Is there something simple I am missing? Or do I need to take another approach on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this turned out to be one of those brain dead moments where I missed something in my testing process.  I am filling in the details of why it was failing in the hope that it saves someone else some of the frustration I have experienced while working on it.

First it is important to know that I was not actually testing multiple packages, I was trying to get my base structure worked out with the first package, then apply it to the rest when I thought I had it fairly close, this was to help reduce the number of changes I needed to replicate across the group of packages.  To do this I was manually adding the registry entry in question, prior to running the package, there by simulating a prior install.

What I neglected to do was actually create the directory referenced by the registry entry.  I was walking through the process with a co-worker, and in the course of explaining it I noticed this section of the log:

```
Action start 8:26:16: AppSearch.
MSI (c) (BC:D4) [08:26:16:505]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (BC:D4) [08:26:16:506]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (BC:D4) [08:26:16:507]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (BC:D4) [08:26:16:507]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding NETFRAMEWORK35 property. Its value is '#1'.
Action ended 8:26:16: AppSearch. Return value 1.
```

And it occurred to me to try creating the directory referenced by the registry value as well as the registry value itself.  Once the directory was there, everything started working properly.

Apparently when you tell the `RegistrySearcher` that the value is a directory, it only sets the value into the property when said directory actually exists.  This detail never came up in my searches on the topic, and is not clear in the documentation I have found, though in retrospect I can see where it is implied.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check a verbose log to see if the properties are set as you expect.
2. Use [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see if the ControlEvent is as you expect. UI is additive, so you have to take extra steps when you want to *replace* the stock UI. For example, see http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2008/08/customised-uis-for-wix.html.

Comment: I followed the general process outlined in your link when trying to customize the UI.  As near as I can tell everything looks correct in Orca.  But when examining the log files it appears that my registry searches are never happening.

Comment: Use Orca to verify that the searches are present in the AppSearch table.

Comment: They were in the table, and I have now tracked down the actual problem.  Thanks for the assistance.